# Magento Admin URL returns 404, after changing <use> xml parameter

Tags: routing, magento-1.9.4, custom-admin-url

I've installed a module which didn't work as expected.

As a fix I tried changing the admin `use` parameter in the config.xml as i noticed it was the old router coding style.

After changing `<use>admin</use>` to `<use>customadminurl</use>` the admin panel is now inacessible. It just returns 404 error page.

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <ordercomment before="Mage_Adminhtml">Tech18_OrderComment_Adminhtml</ordercomment>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

I've tried to change the routing to the new style without the use parameter, but this didn't fix it.

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                   ...
```

I've tried:

- purging cache via n98-magerun
- revert changes
- checking conflicts via n98-magerun
- reindexing
- disabling the module
- Changing admin url to non-custom (default "admin") both in database and local.xml
- Checking rewrites table
- checking all log files
- checking `core_config_data` for issues
- enabling security, backwards extension compatibility in

( https://marketplace.magento.com/18thtechnology-order-notification-of-creator.html#bv_questions)

Comment: May be redis related - n98-magerun does not seem to purge redis cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a redis cache issue